# How to remove files once everyday from a directory of rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, daemon

I need to remove files from a specific folder once everyday at certain time. I found a gem 'whenever' to do this but I don't want to use a gem for this single purpose. Is there any other way to do this without using the gem?

Comment: Yes, just write a cron task yourself.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned above you should write your own script for that.

If you are on linux you can enter this into a shell.

```
crontab -l
```

This will display all your jobs.

Now let's create a job:

```
crontab -e
```

Enter this into the script:

```
00 00 * * * bash path/to/your/script.sh
```

These numbers and stars are the notations for the unix/linux program crontab you can check them out [the manual page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) or you enter in your shell:

**man crontab**.

What happend so far?

We have set up a daily crontab, which calls our script /path/to/your/script.rb.

Now we can add some actions to our script like deleting all files in a folder.

creat a file called script.sh.
And set execute permissions on that script like so:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

You can test your script with the command in your shell.

```
./script.sh
```

or

```
bash script.sh
```

or

```
sh script.sh
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -r /path/to/the/files/you/want/to/delete/*
```

You said that you need that script to run on a spesific time. Let's say you want to run it every 10 minutes.

You would add this into your crontab.

***/10 * * * * bash /path/to/your/script.sh**

If you enter "crontab examples" in a search-engine you will get plenty of results.

Let me know if you need a ruby version of that script.
Besides that I like the fact that you don't want to use a gem.
Just not sure if the maintainer will actually maintain the gem for the next few years ...

If you are on windows you can do ... I don't care ... google for yourself for something like "Add Scheduled and execute powershell script"